Inequality for relative entropy of two Bernoulli distributions
What is the simplest way to prove the following inequality: $2(y-z)^2 \leq y \ln \frac{y}{z} + (1-y) \ln \frac{1-y}{1-z}$ where $y \in (0,1)$ and $z \in (0,1)$.

This is just a special case of Pinsker's inequality. For a more ad hoc approach, use calculus.

Consider $\text{(rhs - lhs)}$ and minimize with respect to $(y,z)$. It is simple

thank you @ClaudeLeibovici, I get the critical point at (0.5, 0.5) with a minimum equal to 0, show that the Hessian is PSD and evaluate the function on its domain to verify that it is nonnegative. However, this was somewhat lengthy. I was aiming for something more concise by using an identity such as $\ln x \leq x-1$.

I do not think (but I may be wrong) that inequalities would be useful.

@GaétanMarceauCaron You may give your attempt, or source, or context.
